# Javascript for loop and if statement counter variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function analyse(data) {
    var counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].closed == true) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    $scope.totalOpen = data.length - counter;
    $scope.totalClosed = counter;
}
```

I am writing a simple function that iterates an array and increment `counter` if the object inside the array's value is true. However, looks like the `counter` variable inside the `if` statement does not have the same scope as a `counter` variable just above `for` loop. Therefore, `totalClosed` variable only gets assigned zero even though there are some objects those have closed as `true`. I think I am not understanding the concept of scoping in Javascript properly. Can anyone help me out, please?

Comment: Post example `data` please.

Comment: I think this will helo you : https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes

Comment: Whats in data? counter definitely has the right scope.

Comment: it is in right scope

Comment: My guess is the loop or the if check is not right.... console.log() or debugger is your friend. `console.log(i, data[i].closed, (data[i].closed == true));`

Comment: Side note, this logic could be reduced with a `filter(...).length`

Comment: My bad guys it was the data issue at least you guys gave me a confident on the scoping part thank you guys and sorry :)

Comment: @JosephMun don't be sorry, we all make mistakes. I'm sure I speak for all of us when I say we are just happy we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > JavaScript has two scopes – global and local. Any variable declared outside of a function belongs to the global scope, and is therefore accessible from anywhere in your code. Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions. Because local scope in JavaScript is created by functions, it’s also called function scope. When we put a function inside another function, then we create nested scope.

There is no problem with your counter scope.This is a working sample based on your question:

```js
data=[
{
"closed":true
},{
"closed":false
}]

function analyse(data) {
    var counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].closed == true) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    var totalOpen = data.length - counter;
    var totalClosed = counter;
    console.log(totalClosed);
    return totalClosed;
}
console.log(analyse(data))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail explanation on the concept of scope :)

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Taplar's side note, you could accomplish this goal more cleanly with a filter:

```
function analyse(data) {
    var closedItems = data.filter(function (item) { return item.closed });
    var totalClosed = closedItems.length;
    var totalOpen = data.length - totalClosed;
    console.log(totalOpen)
    console.log(totalClosed)
}
```

Or, in ES6 syntax:

```
const analyze = (data) => {
    const closedItems = data.filter(item => item.closed);
    const totalClosed = closedItems.length;
    const totalOpen = data.length - totalClosed;
    return {totalOpen, totalClosed}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra advice :)